# Why does Meta award badges and inherit reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

I understand that you don't get reputation in Meta as it's a part of AskDifferent, and meta.stackoverflow is a bigger "independent" site which does.

But why doesn't it show badges from main site here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Badges on Meta mean different things — for example, the answer badges on Meta means that you've answered a question regarding how the site functions, not the site itself. This is substantially different due to the difference in subject matter.

<sup>As an aside, [reputation is tracked independently on Meta](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/mortarboard), just not shown.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

My view is that the badges do depend on the meta or non meta site so can be split up - the rep does not give any extra privileges to the meta site so there is no point in a separate reputation here.

I would note that meta.stackoverflow is getting changed so that there will be a site for StackOverflow and an overall site for all Stackexchange sites